# Unable to access vector data stored in .dat file in c++

Tags: c++

While I am trying to access the vector type of data using c++, stored in .dat file I am getting an error (didn't read vector data from the file).
To isolate the error, I tried a few things, first I run the below code as usual for a single disease. At that moment, it shows the data from the vector. But when I comment the `d.addDisease();` from `int main()` section. It does not show the data. Although, I can see that the data has been stored already from the above process. I search for the solution but didn't find that work for this code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Symptom {
    public:
    vector<string> symptomList;
    string symptom;
    string fileName = "disease.dat";
    char ch;

    public:
    // call this function to add list of symptoms for a disease
    void addSymptom() {
        int i = 0;
        cout<<"Enter symptom for disease:"<<endl;

        do {
            // inserting each symptom in symptomList
            cout<<++i<<". ";
            getline(cin, symptom);
            symptomList.push_back(symptom);

            cout<<"Do you have next symptom to enter or not?(y/n)";
            cin>>ch;
            cin.get();// very usefull while using getline inside the loop
        } while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');      
    }

    // show all the symptoms for a disease
    void showSymptom() {
        cout << "List of symptoms:"<<endl;

        for (auto it = symptomList.begin();
         it != symptomList.end(); ++it)
        cout << " - " << *it << endl;
    }
};

class Disease {
    public:
    Symptom symptoms;
    string fileName = "disease.dat";

    // adding disease information to the file
    void addDisease() {
        char ch;
        ofstream outfile(fileName, ios::binary | ios::out);
        //outfile.open(fileName);

        if(!outfile.is_open()) {
            cout<<"Error while opening the file.";
            return;
        }

        do {
            symptoms.addSymptom();
            outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this),sizeof(*this));
            cout<<"\nDo you have next disease details to enter or not?(y/n)";
            cin>>ch;
        } while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y');
        outfile.close();
    }

    // reading disease information from the file
    void getDisease() {  
        ifstream infile(fileName, ios::binary);
        
        if(!infile.is_open()) {
            cout<<"Error while opening the file.";
            return;
        }

        while(!infile.eof()) {
            if(infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this),sizeof(*this))) { 
                symptoms.showSymptom(); 
            }
        }
        infile.close();
    }
};

int main() {
    Disease d;
    d.addDisease(); // add disease details
    d.getDisease(); // show disease details

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this),sizeof(*this));` is wrong for all kinds of reasons. Your class is not a trivial type, you cannot just dump its bytes into a files (e.g.: `std::vector` internally manages its memory via dynamic allocations, you just wrote a random pointer address to a file)

Comment: Search for serialization and you'll probably get some more hints.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot

```
outfile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this),sizeof(*this))
```

The `this` pointer points to an object which is not a POD type. The `vector` has allocated structures in memory which won't be written. You can search and read on deep-copy to understand the problem, but for a solution, you want to search and read on serialization, and even better, on portable serialization.

For example: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

Edit: Being a POD type is not even enough for a memcpy to work. I'm not sure what the right term is, here, but the cases where a mempcy would work are very limited. Some people refer to Bitwise Copy Semantics. Basically, follow the serialization faq and don't mempcy :-)

Comment: I don't think the term "POD" is applicable here. POD can contain pointers too.